# Prevent updating html with some conditions in MVC Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have the following code in my View,
It's for searching in a site, a user can submit the following form multiple times.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("Search", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "SearchContents",
    LoadingElementId = "SearchAjaxLoader",
    OnSuccess = "SearchLoadContentsOnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "SearchLoadContentsOnFailure",
    OnBegin = "SearchLoadContentsOnBegin",
    OnComplete = "SearchLoadContentsOnComplete",
}))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <input type="text" name="Search" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

I wanna reject old ajax results and show the latest ajax result only.
In a non mvc Ajax form, I was creating an array as ajax counter and compare the server responses with it to prevent update html.
I wanna know how I can prevent `Ajax.BeginForm` to update Html on some conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example I will demonstrate with an `OnSuccess` call, you can do this for each event you wish to handle.

In your `AjaxOptions` remove this to prevent the replace;

```
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "SearchContents",
```

In you `SearchLoadContentsOnSuccess` JavaScript method, without seeing the method I am guesing it will be something like this:

```
function SearchLoadContentsOnSuccess()
{
    // Do something
}
```

Change it to this:

```
function SearchLoadContentsOnSuccess(e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Now the `e` parameter will contain the data that is sent back from your ajax call.

In your updated method, I would simply check the response and act acordingly.
As an example if you response contains a value and results property:

```
function SearchLoadContentsOnSuccess(e)
{
    // Do something 
    $(e.value == 1)
        {
          $('#SearchContents').html(e.results);
        }
}
```

You would simply change the javascript in the above method to suite your needs.